# angular calling api twice which causes entity framework to throw a duplicate exception

Tags: asp.net, angular, entity-framework

Hey guys noobie here tried searching for this problem and asking on my programming discord but no one seems to know or maybe I am just asking the question poorly.

Basically when I create a user by using my register button I step through the code in the debugger and it seems like it's calling the action method twice? after going through the entire action it creates the user but then throws a duplicate unique ID exception on the username.

If I do this through postman though and send the same request it does not call the api twice nor does it throw the exception

Comment: please share stackblitz code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As it is currently written, it is impossible for us to help with your issue. Consider creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or including some code in your question. Since you think the action method is being called twice, please show us how you call the action method as well as the action method itself

Comment: hey thanks a bit new here I am on my way to my campus right now but I will be going to the computer lab for a few hours before class, I will try to post both the front end caller and the action method receiving it.

Sorry about that.